# Oracle Query - Select query by combining two columns multiple times

Tags: oracle

My table look like

```
col1 col2 col3
a      b   c
d      e   f
```

i need select query some thing like

```
select * from <table name> where (col1='a' and col2='b') 
and (col1='d' and col2='e');
```

Can any one help on this?

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? the question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that your intention is to select both rows. So you should use OR condition.

```
select * from <table name> 
where (col1='a' and col2='b') 
or (col1='d' and col2='e');
```